# How to get aspnet mvc DropDownList item with jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was trying to get a text from the DropdownList like that :

```
$('#test option:selected').text()
```

But not working.

```
 <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.DropDownList("Percentage", new SelectList(items, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "test" }))
 </div>
```

And de Js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#test").change(function () {
    var result = $("#test option:selected").text();
    alert(result)     
});
```

but still, nothing.

Comment: did any error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to fix your DropDownList. Right now you have your dropdown attributes mixed with your SelectList.

```
 <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.DropDownList("Percentage", new SelectList(items), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "test" })
 </div>
```